# http strict transport security on apache

Tags: security, ssl, https

I could not find one topic on HSTS here on askubuntu.com yet so here it comes:

I want to setup HSTS so that my webserver will force the browsers to use HTTPS.

Does anyone know how to set this up for apache2 in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really yout application that should be setting this imho, but you can use [`Header set`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) to make apache do it:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
```

Comment: Thats also what i tried and i can see that it is implemented in the http header but it is still possible to go to http://address.com so it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Its Really simple you just need to add one line to your .htaccess file on server

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS

Thats it